# How to predict resource requirements vs performance of many to many queries

Tags: sql, query-optimization, rdbms, database-optimization

In a traditional RDBMS,
Many-to-Many Joins are much more resource consuming than Many-to-One joins.

I am observing Many-to-Many queries getting slow past about 10 to 15 millions of lines in tables, using mainstream computers with 3-4 gigabytes of RAM.
Querying Many-to-One relationships, I observed however no slow-down even with 50 Millions of lines.

- How do one predict memory and CPU requirements against expected performance? (Is any benchmark available?)
- Past which thresholds is it worth using other solutions instead? (MPP or NoSQL)

Comment: If you want to understand how queries are executed, then learn to use `explai`.

Comment: thanks @Gordon-Linoff. Does the explain command realy allow to predict memory and CPU requirements and provides benchmark regarding many to many realtionships ?

Comment: In general, yes, but that depends on the database.

Comment: I am using postgresql. I'll have a look if the explain command can provide effective hints on optimal memory and cpu requirement, also any feedback on the subject from the community is welcomed

Comment: @Gordon-Linoff, to my knowledge and rough looking back to postgres documentation, CPU effort estimates are provided even if converted into disk-page units (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/performance-tips.html), but I see no memory requirements nor speed forcast given memory and cpu parameters.

Comment: In fact I am looking for - a theorical explanation of why Many2Many join is so much resouce consuming and for - numbers, or any other systematic way, allowing to predict the threshold beyond which Many2Many or even Many2One join will no longer be possible on a single node given speed and availability requirements.

Comment: Read about (logical & physical) relational query optimization/implementation, in general & any particular DBMS. Your notion that "join is so much resource consuming" is ill-founded. This is like asking why recursion or looping "is so much resource consuming"--*it does a lot of stuff that needs doing*. "Much" *compared to what*? Or do you just want *estimates*? (Anyhow, performance is somewhat a chaotic function of a zillion factors.) PS Please edit clarifications into your question, comments are ephemeral.

Answer (score 0):

> In a traditional RDBMS, why are Many-to-Many Joins so much more resource consuming than Many-to-One joins?

An SQL `FOREIGN KEY` (FK) constraint holds when subrow values for a list of columns also appear elsewhere as a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` (superkey). So for every row in the referencing table there can be only one matching row in the referenced table. So the result of a `JOIN` `ON` equality of a FK & its superkey can output at most one row per row in the FK table. Whereas in general since a `JOIN` returns every possible combination of rows that can be made from input rows that satisfies an `ON` condition, in general there can be many more rows output.

> After all, aren't Many-to-Many relationships just like two Many-to-One relationships?

It's not clear what you mean by "just like" or how you think it suggests or justifies anything. And a join is not a relationship. (A table represents a relationship.)

> - How does one predict memory and CPU requirements against expected performance? (Is any benchmark available?)

Many SQL DBMSs have a query planner/optimizer `EXPLAIN` command & others for inquiring about what a query will or did do or cost.

Read about (logical & physical) relational query optimization/implementation, in general & in any particular DBMS. Wikipedia happens to have [a decent article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization). Many textbooks are online.

> - Past which thresholds is it worth using other solutions instead? (MPP or NoSQL)

Re NoSQL search my answers, of which the most recent are:
[How to convert an existing relational database to a key-value store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45294578/3404097)
[How does noSQL perform horizontal scaling and how it is more efficient than RDBMS scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44200388/3404097)
[Reasonable Export of Relational to Non-Relational Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44313877/3404097)

RDBMSs offer generic straightforward querying with certain computational complexitiy & optimization opportunities. Relatively speaking, other systems specialize, with certain aspects improved at the expense of others.